# Declaring an extern variable in a header file

Tags: c++, c, extern

I have declared an extern **global** variable inside my main.**h** header file like this:

```
extern int variable;
```

Then, I defined the same global variable inside my main.**c** file like this:

```
int variable = 16;
```

The thing is that I am using another file called **test.c**, and I have included main.**h** header included inside. But I cannot gain access the the "**16**" value that I defined the extern with inside main.**c**. When I call "variable" inside **test.c**, the value of "variable" is "**0**". Should not any .c file that includes my main.**h** header have access to the "**16**" value since I have already defined my "variable" inside main.**c**???

Thanks

Comment: Yes, `test.c` should see the `16`. So you need to show us a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: By what you have described, the value of `variable` in `test.c`, should be 16.  ***[You have described it correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c)***:  Create variable with extern scope in header file.  Define same variable in a .c, assigning an initialization value.  Access variable in any other .c file that #includes the .h in which extern variable is created.

Comment: Make sure that "`int variable=16;`" statement is outside of all functions, or it won't be an `extern`.  If it's inside a function, that will just be a local variable that no other function can see.

Comment: It seems to be likely that some other variable with the same name overshadows the global one, in one cpp file or another. Impossible to say without actual source.

Comment: [existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c/1433387#1433387). Your question may have already been answered here.

Answer (score 1):

When your Including your `main.h` header file, the copy of the file will included in the `main.c` program.

when your alterate into the main.c file , it will not affect the original file.So the value will not affect the original file, and when your are including the file again in the `test.c` file .

Then the copy of the `main.h` will added to the test.c file

Answer (score 1):

You are just including the file main.h in the programs.
When you include in main.c the variable will be 16 and the value will be updated in the main.h.
But when you compile the test.c the value of variable will be 0 initially.
So when you print the value it will be 0.

main.c and test.c will be executed in two separate process, so if the value changes in the main.c it will be not updated in the test.c process.

Only within the single process the value will be updated.